# How can I delete Linkedin js files?

Tags: wordpress, page-speed, optimization, social-media, linkedin

**Data**

I have been working to improve about "site loading speed" on my wordpress website for a while. Also I have a Linkedin account for website.

**Problem**

My latest research showed that these links collect data and also because of these links the website doesn't open before 7 seconds.

Example links according to gtmetrix conclusions:
Remove the following redirect chain if possible.

- dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/...
- bizographics.com/collect/...
- us-west-2.dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/...
- us-west-2.dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/...
- secure.adnxs.com/...
- dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/...

**What did I do?**

- I tried these programs: Junkware Removal, AdwCleaner but nothing
  happened.
- I delete my website links from Linkedin account but it didn't work.
- I used optimization plugins but it became worse.

**Question**

Where are these files? There is nothing in the header.php file or connected js file about the links above. How can I prevent these links affecting my website?

Comment: You don't say if you are using a CMS (WordPress, Joomla) or it is a custom site.  That info might help get an answer

Comment: @Steve thanks, I added as tag but I forgot to add to the question.

Comment: the files are likely in a plugin.  Check the source code of your site, it will give you a hint

Comment: @Steve Thanks for answer, according to your answer I checked plugins, source code and finally database records. I delete some of the unnecesssary tables from database. After I did this I checked with gtmetrix and tools.pingdom again. According to new results, the problem was solved but I'm not sure whether table deleting or not is real solution. I hope I won't run across this problem again.

Comment: I closed this because you indicate that problem went away but you aren't entirely sure about why.